# How can you program a UITextField's keyboard to open on viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I want my UITextField's keyboard to stay open for the entire time I use this view controller. I don't want it to only open when my user touches the text field. In order to do this, I was hoping I would call the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method by doing this:

```
EDIT: thanks everyone, I just noticed I called my UITextField a UIImage field for some reason in the interface.
```

Comment: use [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder] in viewDidLoad.

Comment: @CRDave - Are you sure it is not viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad method?

Comment: na doesn't work @CRDave

Comment: I tried viewDidAppear also. Thanks though

Comment: Are you sure your text field is not nil ?

Comment: Set your delegate in viewDidLoad and the firstResponder in viewDidAppear.

Comment: @bmende either your outlet to (or code to establish) your textfield is not setup, or you are calling the textField's delegate or you do not have viewDidAppear's full parameter listing (the animated part). The solutions given to you will work if you have the background elements established properly. Post more code/information if you are still having problems.

Comment: I'm positive my outlet is set up. I made some edits above if you want to look at it

Comment: Your textField is a UIImageView?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` delegate method is not something that you call from your code. The OS calls the method when that particular event occurs, and you put code in there to run when the event is fired (similar to putting code in `viewDidLoad` for your view controller).

To show the keyboard whenever the view controller appears, simply call the UITextField's `becomeFirstResponder` method in the view controller's `viewDidAppear` method like this:

```
[self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Don't forget to create an `IBOutlet` parameter for the UITextField, link it in Interface Builder, and replace `self.myTextField` above with the outlet that you created.

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger your `textview` in `viewDidAppear` method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This is the way to do it, are you sure self.myTextField isn't Nil ?